# java code problem

Tags: java

i have a bean called empbeans.java which calls dao class(userdao.java) used for inserting data into a table named emp_leaves.It inserts the values based on the ename which is brought from the session.i have a small coding problem.It is displaying a message that "Sorry! Could Not Apply For Leave!".Is there any error in userdao.java ?plz solve.

here is  the code.

## empbeans.java

```
public void apply(ActionEvent evt) {
    ename = util.getSession().getAttribute("ename").toString();
    boolean done= userdao.apply(this);
    if ( done ) {
        reason =  "";
        leavedate="";
        message = "Applied For Leave Successfully!";
    }
    else
        message = "Sorry! Could Not Apply For Leave!";
}
```

## userdao.java

```
public static boolean apply(empbeans e) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    PreparedStatement ps1=null;
    try {

        con = Database.getConnection();
        ps1=con.prepareStatement("select eid from employee where ename=?");
        ps1.setString(1,e.getEname());
        ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into emp_leaves values(?,?,?,default)");
        ps.setInt(1,rs.getInt(1));
        ps.setString(1,e.getLeavedate());
        ps.setString(2,e.getReason());
        int count = ps.executeUpdate();
        return count == 1;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in inserting into time sheet   -->" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        Database.close(con);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not get any exception on the console?

Comment: Is there something actually inserted in the db?  This could be an issue with the jdbc driver.

Comment: erm...maybe you really cannot apply for leave

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `rs.next();`. Because of which, you will have problems in `ps.setInt(1,rs.getInt(1));`

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why the apply method need variable evt when actually the method never uses it.

And then please change the code to this to be able to understand what the exception returned :

**userdao.java**

```
public static void apply(empbeans e) throws Exception{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    PreparedStatement ps1=null;
   try {

        con = Database.getConnection();
       ps1=con.prepareStatement("select eid from employee where ename=?");
       ps1.setString(1,e.getEname());
       ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();
       ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "insert into emp_leaves values(?,?,?,default)");
       ps.setInt(1,rs.getInt(1));
        ps.setString(1,e.getLeavedate());
        ps.setString(2,e.getReason());
        int count = ps.executeUpdate();
   }catch(Exception e) 
   {e.printStackTrace(); throw e;}

}
```

**empbeans.java**

```
public void apply(ActionEvent evt) {
  String  ename = util.getSession().getAttribute("ename").toString();
  try{
   userdao.apply(this);
   reason =  "";
   leavedate="";
   message="Leave applied successfully";  
  }catch(Exception e)
  { 
   message = "Sorry! Could Not Apply For Leave! reason:"+e.getMessage();
   }
 }
```

Remember, error is not being thrown for nothing.

From here you can get the exact reason why it's not working, which I guess rs.next().